GCC output Arm64 assembly instructions
I have a c program on a raspberry pi. I am trying to get the assembly of the code I have written. As the Raspberry Pi is an ARM64 processor I was expecting the assembly to be in ARM64.
Command: gcc -S main.c
Code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 1;
}

Assembly:
    .arch armv8-a
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
    .align  3
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world!"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .type   main, %function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 29, -16
    .cfi_offset 30, -8
    mov x29, sp
    adrp    x0, .LC0
    add x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
    bl  puts
    mov w0, 1
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 16
    .cfi_restore 30
    .cfi_restore 29
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:  .arch armv8-a
    .file   "first.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
    .align  3
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world!"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global main
    .type   main, %function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 29, -16
    .cfi_offset 30, -8
    mov x29, sp
    adrp    x0, .LC0
    add x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
    bl  puts
    mov w0, 1
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 16
    .cfi_restore 30
    .cfi_restore 29
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits

This is AT&T syntax (I think) and I want to get the ARM64 assembly. I have been trying options like -masm but the compiler throws an error stating that it's an unrecognized option.
How would I get GCC to generate ARM64 assembly?

You need a cross-compiler. https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Do I need a cross compiler if it's running on an ARM64 system and is compiling programs normally that work?
If need be I can download the cross compiler it just seemed like an odd thing to do as it's already running on the system that is the target of the cross compilation.

if both the host and target are the same arch, then no, no need for a cross-compiler.

No, you are building on an arm64 machine so the asm is arm64. Destination on the left and source arg(s) on the right.

The AT&T syntax distinction only applies to x86 (and maybe some others?) but not to ARM. gcc outputs the same standard assembly syntax specified by the ARM company.

That output really is ARM64 assembly code.  There's nothing wrong with it.
There are a lot of directives (dot commands) generated by the compiler, but those are not actually assembly instructions.
The actual assembly code is this filtered portion:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
    mov x29, sp
    adrp    x0, .LC0
    add x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
    bl  puts
    mov w0, 1
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 16
    ret


@DavidT don't be so hard on yourself. Compiler generated asm has lots of extra stuff in it. You just "have to know" this. Now you do... There's a "first time" for everyone

How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?. Or simply use https://godbolt.org/ and let it handle everything
